# laravel 5.2 mailgun send succcefuly but not found in inbox

Tags: php, laravel-5, mailgun

I try to send email by mailgun at my application on localhost. 
when i submit. email message with return appear but I don't find ant message in inbox
-this my function

```
public function send_mail(Request $request)
  {

    $rules = array(
        'name'       => 'required|max:50',
        'email'      => 'required',
        'mobile' => 'required|max:15',
        'message' => 'required|max:1000'

    );

    $v= \Validator::make($request->all(),  $rules);
    if ($v->fails()) {
           return redirect()->back()->withErrors($v->errors())->withInput($request->input());
         }else{
           $data = array(
          'name' => $request->name,
          'email' => $request->email,
          'mobile' => $request->mobile,
          'message' => $request->message,

          );
       Mail::send('website.contactus.mymessage', $data, function($message) use ($data){
         $message->from($data['email']);
         $message->to('azharnabil013@yahoo.com');
         $message->subject($data['message']);
         });


         return redirect('contact-us')->with('message', 'لقد تم ارسال الرساله بنجاح!');

         }
```

-I add the package
   `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0"`

-make mailgun account
-this my env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=***from mailgun account
MAIL_PASSWORD=***from mailgun account
```

-and edit mail.php and sevices in config

Comment: What do [your Mailgun logs](https://mailgun.com/app/logs) say?

Comment: log give accepted message then failed message in the same moment 12/14/16 06:45 AM Accepted: postmaster@******.mailgun.org → ******@yahoo.com 'لو سمحتو انا عايز اعمل اعلان على الموقع بتاعكم لمدة ممكن يتكلف كام 'ر12/14/16 06:45 AM Failed: postmaster@****.mailgun.org → *****@yahoo.com 'لو سمحتو انا عايز اعمل اعلان على الموقع بتاعكم لمدة ممكن يتكلف كام ' Server response: 554 554 5.7.9 Message not accepted for policy reasons. See https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/SLN7253.html

Comment: Message not accepted for policy reasons.

Comment: So your msg is getting to Mailgun, but Yahoo is rejecting it. If you click on the error msg in the Mailgun logs you might see more info.